# Is there a method for dividing an Address string into 3 separate strings using regex

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am currently working on a project that requires me to divide an address into its street number, its street name, and if it has a suite, into its suite name.
EX: 1360 WHITE OAK RD STE F -----> 1360 | White Oak RD | STE F

I am currently using google sheet and using the =regexextract() functionality that uses Regex to parse the string into different columns. This is how I am currently dividing the number and the street (given the full address is in column B.

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B,"[0-9]*")) ---->gets the number EX:(1360)`

`=ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B," [a-zA-Z0-9 ]+")) ---->gets the street address including the suite number with a white space at the begining EX:( WHITE OAK RD STE F)`

The question I am struggling with is how do I remove the white space from the 2nd formula and also prevent it from getting the suite text (which always starts with STE). Lastly what would be a formula for grabbing the suite text and number.

Thanks and I appreciate any help you can give!

Comment: Proper address parsing is not something for the faint of heart. If you're just working with a well defined set of data and this is homework then something is achievable but it will break heinously once you let loose to real-world data.

Comment: This is not a homework thing with a good set of data unfortunately. Right now the data for this project is currently being sanitized by a team combing through it. This is a onetime thing for a sanitized set of data. I just don't have much regex experience. The person in charge of the data before I joined the project had no experience with managing information or sanitizing inputs from forms. So now we are stuck brute forcing a lot of stuff.

Comment: `=REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B,"STE.*$")` would get you the suite

Comment: This is getting me on the right path. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Sheets you could use the following 3 formulas:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"^[0-9]*")
=REGEXREPLACE(B1,"^[0-9\s]*|\s*STE.*$", "")
=REGEXEXTRACT(B1,"STE.*$")
```

I would have used lookbehinds but they are not universally supported in all browsers (yet).

I'm not a Google Sheets expert so I've opted to remove `ArrayFormula` and replace the `B1:B` with just `B1` since they seemed superfluous.

Comment: Thank you so much, The arrayformula is there to apply it to the entire column, the b1:B just selects the entire column. appreciate all the help!

Comment: *"...I've opted to remove ArrayFormula"*. Please have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64796606/1527780) on how it can be incorporated.

Answer (score 2):

The formula provided by [MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2191572/monkeyzeus) works perfectly giving no issues whatsoever.

In case though you have your **results in adjacent columns** you can **use a single formula on every row** like

```
=SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1,"([0-9]+) (.+) (STE.*)","$1♣︎$2♣︎$3"),"♣︎")
```

**Or even use an Arrayformula to get your results for an entire column**

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(B1:B,"([0-9]+) (.+) (STE.*)","$1♣︎$2♣︎$3"),"♣︎")))
```

What the formula does

- using parenthesis `()` we divide the text into 3 groups `$1`, `$2`, `$3`
- `$1♣︎$2♣︎$3` adding the character `♣︎` (could be any character that does not interfere with the formula) we prepare uor text for the `SPLIT` function
- we split our now formed into groups text, to adjacent columns wherever `♣︎` is found
- The `Arrayformula` applies all the above to every single row in column `B` while `IFERROR` makes sure we don't get any errors (like when empty cells are found).

[image: How to use REGEXREPLACE and SPLIT in an Arrayformula]

---

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)

Comment: I like it, thanks for explaining `ArrayFormula()` and various other functions :)

Comment: My initial goal was to achieve what you've done here but I didn't feel like reading through all of the function documentation

Comment: *"My initial goal was... "* Happens to everyone :)